# Play mp3 from web with MPMoviePlayerController over 3G

Tags: ios

In my app I use MPMoviePlayerController to play an mp3 file from a web server. This plays while downloading the whole file, which is fine over WiFi. But now I want it to work over 3G (and get it into the app store). How do I get it to just buffer the next 10 seconds or so (as per apple rules)? I'm digging through the documentation on AVPlayer, HTTP Live streaming, etc, but I'm still confused about the best way to do this. With so many podcast apps out there, I'm suprised there aren't more tutorials/libraries about it.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I investigated this as well, and I was not able find a way to limit the look-ahead buffer using MPMoviePlayerController. I believe you would have to load chunks at the network layer and feed them in at the AVFoundation layer, but I have not attempted this myself.

That said, I can confirm that you can get an app approved that plays mp3 files using MPMoviePlayerController over both WiFi and 3G connections. In my app I added a setting so the user can decide whether to enable mp3 downloads over 3G or not, although I don't know if that was needed to get approved. I provided it so users didn't inadvertently incur bandwidth costs.